# Problems accessing RESTful service in dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jboss

I am having issues accessing my restful service in Eclipse. When I run the project, the browser loads with the expected 404 page because it doesn't have a front page, but when I browse to the link that returns JSON formatted database entries nothing happens.

I used to be able to visit /movies and a list of films and all their details would appear in JSON format, now nothing happens.

below is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="movies">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLMoviesDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I haven't actually changed anything, but the expected console output is not produced and none of my methods are accessed. Everything is deployed properly and the relevant Hibernate logs appear but no errors of any kind.

I hope I haven't left anything out.

This is the restful method I have previously been able to access.

```
@Path("/movies")
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MovieWS {

private static String[] columnNames = { "title", "description", "director", "country", "yearMade", "budget",
        "rentalPrice", "onLoan", "picture" };

private static Hashtable<String, Object> columnsAndValues = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

@EJB
private MovieDAO movieDao;

/*
 * This method receives requests for 'all movies', when nothing is appended
 * to the URL
 */

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response findAll() {
    System.out.println("Get all movies");
    List<Movie> movie = movieDao.getAllMovies();
    return Response.status(200).entity(movie).build();
}
```

As you can see, if this was receiving anything then it would do a print. As I said, this was all working fine. If I move it to a dynamic web project it works fine, but if I put it in a maven project it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're sure your persistence is well set, you probably want to share the code for the servlet etc. that's supposed to return the JSON.

Comment: I've added some code, thanks for the response.

Comment: Have you debugged up to `return Response.status(200).entity(movie).build();` and checked the line above, whether the `movie` variable contains your movies?

Comment: Yes. All of these were working before. I have also check for the relevant database entries and nothing is even being accessed. In the console output I see that persistence.xml is found and the bindings take place, but nothing else beyond that. It should at least print me errors on the console if the code was being accessed at all.